# Remove (*) from the chat titlebar after focus

Tags: feature-request, chat

To reproduce:
- get mentioned in chat while chat windows is out of focus
- bring up the chat window

If the mention is recent enough I can see the highlight, if not when I click on the green number over my avatar I'll be sent to the mention.

Now, the mention bubble and the chat window title (`*`) are still there until I chat something or until I click the mention bubble. If I don't have/want to reply, when the chat windows looses focus I'll still have the (`*`) in the title and when I come back the mention bubble over my avatar.

Is this a bug? If it's a feature it's very annoying !

It doesn't make sense to have it after the windows receives focus when mentioned recent enough and mention highlight is visible.

Comment: I see this got from a [bug] to a [feature-request], may be both, it always felt like a bug to me

Comment: Y U KEEP IGNORING ME??!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to keep the current behaviour at least for the bubble. The asterisk in the title could/should probably be reset when the window regains focus.

Sometimes you might end up with multiple notifications before you come back to the window and trying to adjust the bubble to only count ones that aren't visible is a lot of effort for not a lot of benefit.

Comment: the `(*)` title really should go, you never know when you're mentioned again and bad for OCD types :P also a fast fix, the bubble adjust is another deal but would be nice maybe if max 2 mentions and really really recent. i guess chat is not really a priority